# how to create active/inactive status using an if-then statement and looping through all rows VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create a project management macros and I have coded many parts of it, but I am having trouble with the last piece below.

Each task has a start date (Column D), end date (Column E),and a status (Column K). My initial goal was to check if any of the days within "this week" would fall within the start date and end date for that particular row. I completed this goal and now I would like to loop this formula/code and create a status for every row based on the start date and end date for every individual row.

There are an infinite number of rows, because each project is different and I using this macros as a template.

Does anyone know how to loop this formula through each row until there are no more rows with data in them?

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

```
Sub PM_Schedule() 

'mark as active if this week falls within range D:E

Dim bk As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
    NumRows = Range("$D2", Range("$D2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    ' Select cell D2.
    Range("$D2").Select

    ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
    For x = 1 To NumRows

    Dim D As Integer
    Dim N As Date

    D = Weekday(Now)
    Thismonday = Now() + (2 - D)
    ThisTuesday = Now() + (3 - D)
    ThisWednesday = Now() + (4 - D)
    ThisThursday = Now() + (5 - D)
    ThisFriday = Now() + (6 - D)

    StartDate = xWs.Range("$D2").Value
    EndDate = xWs.Range("$E2").Value

        If Thismonday >= StartDate And Thismonday <= EndDate Then
            Status = "Active"
        ElseIf ThisTuesday >= StartDate And ThisTuesday <= EndDate Then
            Status = "Active"
        ElseIf ThisWednesday >= StartDate And ThisWednesday <= EndDate Then
            Status = "Active"
        ElseIf ThisThursday >= StartDate And ThisThursday <= EndDate Then
            Status = "Active"
        ElseIf ThisFriday >= StartDate And ThisFriday <= EndDate Then
            Status = "Active"
        Else
            Status = "Not Active"
        End If

        xWs.Range("$K2").Value = Status

    Next

        ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

      Next

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this should be close:

```
Sub PM_Schedule()

    'mark as active if this week falls within range D:E
    Dim xWS As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim ThisMonday, ThisFriday, StartDate, EndDate, Status

    Set xWS = ActiveSheet
    ThisMonday = Date + (2 - Weekday(Date)) '<< use Date, not Now
    ThisFriday = ThisMonday + 4

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'It's usually safer to use End(xlUp) than xlDown
    For Each c In xWS.Range(xWS.Range("D2"), _
                            xWS.Cells(xWS.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Cells

        StartDate = c.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value 'D
        EndDate = c.EntireRow.Cells(5).Value   'E

        c.EntireRow.Cells(11).Value = IIf(StartDate <= ThisFriday And EndDate >= ThisMonday, _
                                        "Active", "Not active")
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```